# What's wrong with the konqueror on my Arch Linux?

Tags: kde, plasma5, konqueror

My computer environment is Arch Linux + plasma KDE, yesterday I installed konqueror, restart the computer prompt konqueror crash, I can not through the menu shortcut keys to open konqueror, but through the terminal input konqueror www.google.com can open the browser, Is this what is the reason? How can I open konqueror through the menu shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's the reality that all involved parties decided to no longer develop it and no one else picked the maintainer mantle up.

Unless you are a skilled C++ developer, there is nothing you or I can change about it.

Konqueror is unmaintained and is going to be replaced by Qupzilla soon.

This is an answer from Reddit .

Comment: While this is further clarification, I'm not sure it's an answer to "how can I open konqueror through the menu shortcuts?"

Comment: Yes, but if it is true, I'm going not to use konqueror 